# Woocommerce get cart total price in a number format

Tags: plugins, terms, markdown

Is it possible to get the cart total price without any markup. So without the € symbol? Right now I'm getting the amount with:

```
$totalamount = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
```

this will give €16.50

I tried this also:

```
$totalamount = number_format($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(), 2, '.', '');
```

But this always gives 0.00

Is there a woocommerce get function that will give a number format of the total cart price? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update 2020

**Answer**

See [flytech's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134173/9745) for a solution using the native WooCommerce API.

**Note / Caveat**

If you're going to do proper arithmetic with monetary values, ***always* use signed integers (!) representing the smallest denomination of a given currency** (Cent, Penny, Paisa, Dirham, e.g.).
Only convert back to decimal fractions in the presentation layer of your application *after* all calculations are done.

This holds true regardless of language or framework.

### Original answer

I don't know woocommerce at all and hence there might be a native way as well, but anyhow, this

```
$amount = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
```

should do.

The `preg_replace` eliminates everything but decimal characters and colons.

Should you care to do math with it, the `floatval` converts the value from a string to a numeric one.

Comment: Thanks, I already worked it out with some kind of solution indeed.

Comment: For some countries you have to consider the comma too, try this '#[^\d.,]#'

Comment: I'd warn you about this issue: if you set dots and commas in woocommerce general settings you can have unwanted results with this method. Example: amount = 1.239,90$ can be read as 1,239$. I'd suggest [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063173/woocommerce-get-cart-total-as-number#answer-42433145)

Answer (score 24):

That is what you want:

Working with global variable:

```
global $woocommerce;  
$woocommerce->cart->total;
```

Working with function:

```
WC()->cart->total;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: yes! this works; it strips the currency symbol

Comment: If I use this in the cart it only works properly when the cart is visited, not if someone uses update cart ... anyone know why?

Comment: This should be the correct answer.
Depending on context (e.g. mine), WC()->cart->total also works nicely.

Comment: on any page you declare $woocommerce as global variable and the you can access most of the stuff that you need.

Comment: you can also create another cart variable like this
global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

this contains the cart related stuff;

do a print_r( $cart ); to access the values.

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#288-298